# Google Event Update Using Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to update a few keys of Event already present in the Calendar. I am using Admin User OAuth Tokens for Calling the APIs.

Update API is returning 200 and in some cases updates the keys but most of the time its fails with 200 status code.

If I am trying to update the Summary and End Time of event using PATCH request it is working fine.

```
body = {
    "summary": "Update test"
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2022-09-30T07:00:00+00:00",
    }
}

service.events().patch(calendarId=resource_email, eventId="my_event", body=body).execute()
```

This above code is working fine. BUt when I am trying to update the status or recurrence then they are not getting updated.

```
body_1 = {
    "status": "cancelled",
}


body_2 = {
    "recurrence": ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20221010T115709Z"],
}

service.events().patch(calendarId=resource_email, eventId="my_event", body=body_1).execute()

OR

service.events().patch(calendarId=resource_email, eventId="my_event", body=body_2).execute()
```

Even UPDATE Requests are not working, using update I am not able to update the summary and End time as well.

```
my_event = service.events().get(calendarId=resource_email, eventId="my_event_id").execute()


my_event["recurrence"] = ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20221010T115709Z"]
my_event["summary"] = "recurr update 1"

service.events().update(calendarId=resource_email, eventId="my_event_id", body=my_event).execute()
```

Since the response I am getting is 200 and not 400 so the keys should get updated in Event but they are not. Is there anything I am missing here like syntax or sequence of API Calling

**UPDATE 1**

API Curl

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/veris.in_2d3533353337303430363639@resource.calendar.google.com/events/5ubjdisv2olhe8nn7bfapmrb59/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0Aa4xrXNge0zsviwcYkgsvHaFSbaMcSaM1tzM7BMJ8tyaA9On8g2_oJc0KZoPO-balJpkpSXeNSpaa_XOMGwx19JoUhEYteuoss0spugSmkpdbpOd2KVVw8fZl_N_MZl0WTHGhrIVaJSHx4O2oXanlufY_8eaSgaCgYKATASARESFQEjDvL9FnnnLJnQqCBesPcEFGMh6g0165' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "status": "cancelled"
}'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have narrowed down my issue and the test case when I am not able to update the event.

Lets assume following things

**Admin user** : adminUser@example.com (A1)
**Normal User** : user1@example.com (U1)
**Resource** : R1

- Firstly, I created an event from codebase using `events.insert()` on Resource **R1** (R1 added as attendee) lets say event **E1** with using token of **A1**, here in **E1** Organizer is **R1** and creator is **A1**.
- ON this **E1** , I am successfully Able to perform `PATCH` on summary, status and REcurrance.
- Secondly, I created an event let say **E2** from **U1's** Calendar (from Google Calendar UI) and choose **R1** as room. Here in **E2** Organizer is **U1** and creator is also **U1**.
- ON this **E2** from `events.patch()` and `events.update()`, I am not bble to update summary, status and Recurrance.

From the above two scenarios of **E1** & **E2** , I can only update events which are created by **A1**. But Since A1 is an admin user and all necessary SCOPES are provided when issuing oAuth Tokens so using A1's token one must be able to events Created on any Resource by any user of his Gsuite Organisation.

Comment: try using events().patch rather then events().update()

Comment: @DaImTo I tried. See body_1 & body_2 payload request. They are with PATCH and not working at all despite the fact that I am getting 200 Response.

Comment: Are you applying changes to a recently created event? Can you try with an old event and see if you get the same result?

Comment: @LorenaGomez Yes they are old events and I am getting the same result.

Comment: That's odd, I just tested with the same request you shared and it worked for me. Based on what you shared, I see you're using Python. I followed this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python), I made the same request you shared and `patch` worked for updating the status and recurrence. Is there something different that you're doing in your code before making the request to the Calendar API?

Comment: yes please share a full example including your authorization code

Comment: @LorenaGomez Updated my Question with API Curl.

Comment: @DaImTo Updated my Question with API Curl.

Comment: I'm confused are you using PHP or curl?

Comment: @DaImTo I am using Python but I have replicated the same issue with curl too. Same Token, event & Calendar in curl . Since it will be difficult to share the code snippet and entire Token JSON So I thought Curl will do the job in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: @DaImTo I have narrowed down to the test case which is failing for me. Also, Updated my Question with 2 Test Cases. Can you please check Update 2.

Comment: @user5594493 so what I understand in second scenario is that as a super admin (with admin's token), you're trying to modify an event created by U1 correct? In super admin's Google Calendar UI, do you see U1's calendar events and are you able to modify the event through the UI? And just to double check again, I understood that you're able to modify other properties of the event, except for `recurrence` or `status`?